# Translate the text in my clipboard into another language

Tags: windows, translation, clipboard

I am looking for a program for Windows 10 that can automatically translate the text in my clipboard into another language: e.g., whenever I copy a text in English, it'd translate it into French, so that I can paste it somewhere in French. I know how I could code it (e.g., use Google Tranlate API) but I'd prefer an already existing solution.

Any price or license is fine.

Comment: 2 quick ideas Franck: (1) CopyQ (https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) - with just a little work it will do what you want, but AFAIK not "straight out of the box", (2) one of many web browser extensions designed for this purpose (but you may not want the software to be a browser extension)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Thanks, that seems very useful, you're welcome to add it as an answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  To clarify, you referring to CopyQ, correct?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Thanks, I am interested in both. I didn't know that some web browser extensions could translate the text in my clipboard into another language.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% what you're asking for, but I think having more control is better in case you copy text that's not supposed to be translated, like code.

Anyways, [Crow Translate](https://github.com/crow-translate/crow-translate) has an option to translate selection directly to clipboard. You can set a separate shortcut for that in `Settings` -> `Shortcuts` -> `Translate selected text and copy to clipboard`. It can use Google Translate, Bing Translate, Yandex Translate, LibreTranslate, etc.

Crow Translate is open-source and is available for Windows and Linux.

Comment: Nice find!  I had never heard of it before your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Babylon

[image: Babylon screenshot]

From their site:

Babylon translation software helps you understand the world. You can instantly translate any word that appears on your screen, while also receiving dictionary and Wikipedia results, with only the click of a button.

[Babylon homepage](https://www.babylon-software.com/)